# Ms access conditional sum

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Please assist... to get to the point can Ms access conditional sum like Ms excel.
e.g

SUMIF(range,criteria,[sum_range]) \ SUMIF(O2:AJ6,"<>99",Sheet4!A1:V1)

So the range is the number of columns for a record and the [sum_range] is a reference.

Can this equation be achieved with Ms Access

Can this be done for multiple field? 
i have created an ms access database for Quality department that has questions, weights and options. 
The problem is that... the assessor will capture details of the call using three options (Yes, No and N/A) Yes = different weights (1,2,4,or 10), No = 0 and N/A = 99. With that being said i need to calculate the total assessment sheet score based on the yes, no and exclude the not applicable questions. the assessment sheet has 24 question with different weights.

The total assessment score is 100 and depended on the N/A options selected, the weight of the assessment will decrease and bring about a new total based on the yes and no that were selected.

Is this possible on access?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get a good book or tutorial about how a database like Access works. It is obvious that you come from the spreadsheet world and you will have a hard time if you don't wrap your head around the basics of databases and the differences to Excel.

To answer your question:
You just need a query where you add conditions (or a WHERE-Clause in the SQL view).

Example:

```
SELECT SUM(Fieldname) FROM Tablename WHERE Fieldname2="xy"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the Replay. Can this be done for multiple record? i have created an ms access database for Quality department that has questions, weights and options. The problem is that... the assessor will capture details of the call using three options (Yes, No and N/A) Yes = different weights (1,2,4,or 10), No = 0 and N/A = 99. So i need an equation that will calculate conditionally and sum excluding the not "99". should i create a table of reference... to be honest i am new to access and kind of lost

Comment: Every SQL command works on all records of the specified table(s). This is the fundamental concept of databases. And of course you can sum up values excluding specific rows, like where weight <> 99. You don't need a reference table for that.

Comment: But I really think you should read something about Access first, otherwise you will make bad design choices now and have to redo a lot of work later.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that i was looking for is IIF statement

Solution below

```
2: IIf([Q2]='Yes',1,IIf([Q2]='No',0))
```

For the question that i have i can convert to be a specific number and then can i have all the results and create calculation.